# JSon HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a set of JSON data and I would like to display it in HTML table.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin: 20px auto; width: 500px;">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" id="jsonTable" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            </table>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function addAllColumnHeaders(myList) {
    var columnSet = [];
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        var rowHash = myList[i];
        for (var key in rowHash) {
            if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
                columnSet.push(key);
                headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
    }
    $("#jsonTable").append(headerTr$);

    return columnSet;
}

$.getJSON("data.json", function (data) {
    var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
            var cellValue = data[i][columns[colIndex]];

            if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
        }
        $("#jsonTable").append(row$);
    }
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>

JSON

{
  "WebReport_BillingResp": {
    "summaryTables": [
      {
        "-title": "Capacity License Usage",
        "tableHeaders": {
          "cellValue": [
            { "-val": "Billing Group" },
            { "-val": "Description" },
            { "-val": "Baseline" },
            { "-val": "Total Usage (TB)" },
            { "-val": "Total Cost" }
          ]
        },
        "tableData": [
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "SSP-C-DPS-1T" },
              { "-val": "Simpana® Data Protection Snapshot Management  Serv" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "38" },
              { "-val": "3078" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "Total" },
              {

              },
              {

              },
              { "-val": "38" },
              { "-val": "3078" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "-title": "Client Access License Usage",
        "tableHeaders": {
          "cellValue": [
            { "-val": "Billing Group" },
            { "-val": "Description" },
            { "-val": "Baseline" },
            { "-val": "Total Usage" },
            { "-val": "Total Cost" }
          ]
        },
        "tableData": [
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "Data-aware Client Protection" },
              { "-val": "Data-aware Client Protection" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "343" },
              { "-val": "8232" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "SSP-cSIM-V-A-Client" },
              { "-val": "cSIM Simpana® for VM Protection and Cloud Manageme" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "847" },
              { "-val": "5929" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "SSP-eSIM-B-A" },
              { "-val": "eSIM Simpana® Endpoint Backup/Restore option meter" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "83" },
              { "-val": "145.25" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "Total" },
              {

              },
              {

              },
              { "-val": "1273" },
              { "-val": "14306.25" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "header": {
      "-amountDue": "17384.25",
      "-minimumFee": "0",
      "-custNameValue": "Hipskind test",
      "-dueDate": "3/11/2016",
      "-billDate": "2/11/2016",
      "-billCycle": "1/1/2016 - 1/31/2016",
      "-custNameLabel": "CommCell Group",
      "-totalCost": "17384.25"
    },
    "detailTables": [
      {
        "-title": "Capacity License Usage at CommCell level",
        "tableHeaders": {
          "cellValue": [
            { "-val": "CommCell ID" },
            { "-val": "CommCell Name" },
            { "-val": "Billing Group" },
            { "-val": "Usage (TB)" }
          ]
        },
        "tableData": {
          "cellValue": [
            { "-val": "FBED4" },
            { "-val": "Hipskind TSG Inc - hsob-commserve" },
            { "-val": "SSP-C-DPS-1T" },
            { "-val": "38" }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "-title": "Client Access License Usage at CommCell level",
        "tableHeaders": {
          "cellValue": [
            { "-val": "CommCell ID" },
            { "-val": "CommCell Name" },
            { "-val": "Billing Group" },
            { "-val": "Usage" }
          ]
        },
        "tableData": [
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "FBED4" },
              { "-val": "Hipskind TSG Inc - hsob-commserve" },
              { "-val": "SSP-cSIM-V-A-Client" },
              { "-val": "654" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              {

              },
              {

              },
              { "-val": "SSP-eSIM-B-A" },
              { "-val": "20" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              {

              },
              {

              },
              { "-val": "Data-aware Client Protection" },
              { "-val": "242" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "FC6A2" },
              { "-val": "Hipskind TSG - m1wcomcon01-p" },
              { "-val": "SSP-cSIM-V-A-Client" },
              { "-val": "193" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              {

              },
              {

              },
              { "-val": "SSP-eSIM-B-A" },
              { "-val": "63" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              {

              },
              {

              },
              { "-val": "Data-aware Client Protection" },
              { "-val": "101" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "-title": "Capacity License Usage at Billing Group level",
        "tableHeaders": {
          "cellValue": [
            { "-val": "Billing Group" },
            { "-val": "Lower Limit" },
            { "-val": "Upper Limit" },
            { "-val": "Price per Tier" },
            { "-val": "Usage per Tier" },
            { "-val": "Cost per Tier" }
          ]
        },
        "tableData": [
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "SSP-C-DPS-1T" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "-1" },
              { "-val": "81" },
              { "-val": "38" },
              { "-val": "3078" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "Sub Total" },
              {

              },
              {

              },
              {

              },
              { "-val": "38" },
              { "-val": "3078" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "-title": "Client Access License Usage at Billing Group level",
        "tableHeaders": {
          "cellValue": [
            { "-val": "Billing Group" },
            { "-val": "Lower Limit" },
            { "-val": "Upper Limit" },
            { "-val": "Price per Tier" },
            { "-val": "Usage per Tier" },
            { "-val": "Cost per Tier" }
          ]
        },
        "tableData": [
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "SSP-cSIM-V-A-Client" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "-1" },
              { "-val": "7" },
              { "-val": "847" },
              { "-val": "5929" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "Sub Total" },
              {

              },
              {

              },
              {

              },
              { "-val": "847" },
              { "-val": "5929" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "SSP-eSIM-B-A" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "-1" },
              { "-val": "1.75" },
              { "-val": "83" },
              { "-val": "145.25" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "Sub Total" },
              {

              },
              {

              },
              {

              },
              { "-val": "83" },
              { "-val": "145.25" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "Data-aware Client Protection" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "-1" },
              { "-val": "24" },
              { "-val": "343" },
              { "-val": "8232" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "Sub Total" },
              {

              },
              {

              },
              {

              },
              { "-val": "343" },
              { "-val": "8232" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "-title": "Exception List",
        "tableHeaders": {
          "cellValue": [
            { "-val": "csid" },
            { "-val": "lictype" },
            { "-val": "name" },
            { "-val": "capacityUsage" },
            { "-val": "licenseUsage" }
          ]
        },
        "tableData": [
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "102" },
              { "-val": "1-Touch Server for Unix" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "110" },
              { "-val": "1-Touch Server for Windows" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "100013" },
              { "-val": "Archived Mailboxes" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "206" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "139" },
              { "-val": "Auxiliary Copy Encryption" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "4" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "190" },
              { "-val": "Cloud Storage" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "141" },
              { "-val": "Compliance Search" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "105" },
              { "-val": "Content Addressed Storage" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "100018" },
              { "-val": "CPU Sockets on Hypervisor Hosts" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "160" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "100004" },
              { "-val": "Data Archive Enterprise infrastructure" },
              { "-val": "4017161764864" },
              { "-val": "0" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "85" },
              { "-val": "Data Encryption" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "100002" },
              { "-val": "Data Protection Enterprise infrastructure" },
              { "-val": "158486117744640" },
              { "-val": "0" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "168" },
              { "-val": "De-Duplication Block Level" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "24" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "100016" },
              { "-val": "Dedupe Store Space (TB)" },
              { "-val": "472158879875072" },
              { "-val": "0" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "174" },
              { "-val": "Developer License" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "84" },
              { "-val": "Disk Library Connector (DDO)" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "28" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "100015" },
              { "-val": "Disk Library Space (TB)" },
              { "-val": "653714035572736" },
              { "-val": "0" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "100025" },
              { "-val": "End point sharing users" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "6" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "111" },
              { "-val": "Erase Data" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "63" },
              { "-val": "File System Archiving" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "6" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "91" },
              { "-val": "GridStore" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "163" },
              { "-val": "Hardware Snapshot Enabler" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "4" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "142" },
              { "-val": "Legal Hold" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "11" },
              { "-val": "MediaAgent" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "30" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "N/A" },
              { "-val": "188977207120421" },
              { "-val": "0" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "203" },
              { "-val": "Protected Mailboxes" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "82" },
              { "-val": "VaultTracker Enterprise" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "143" },
              { "-val": "Virtual Server" },
              { "-val": "106550574964102" },
              { "-val": "34" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "39637" },
              { "-val": "90" },
              { "-val": "WORM Media Support" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "102" },
              { "-val": "1-Touch Server for Unix" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "110" },
              { "-val": "1-Touch Server for Windows" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "141" },
              { "-val": "Compliance Search" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "105" },
              { "-val": "Content Addressed Storage" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "100018" },
              { "-val": "CPU Sockets on Hypervisor Hosts" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "23" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "85" },
              { "-val": "Data Encryption" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "100002" },
              { "-val": "Data Protection Enterprise infrastructure" },
              { "-val": "38327672635392" },
              { "-val": "0" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "168" },
              { "-val": "De-Duplication Block Level" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "6" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "100016" },
              { "-val": "Dedupe Store Space (TB)" },
              { "-val": "149842665930752" },
              { "-val": "0" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "174" },
              { "-val": "Developer License" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "84" },
              { "-val": "Disk Library Connector (DDO)" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "7" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "100015" },
              { "-val": "Disk Library Space (TB)" },
              { "-val": "149961393045504" },
              { "-val": "0" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "111" },
              { "-val": "Erase Data" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "91" },
              { "-val": "GridStore" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "142" },
              { "-val": "Legal Hold" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "11" },
              { "-val": "MediaAgent" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "8" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "N/A" },
              { "-val": "25017104048128" },
              { "-val": "0" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "203" },
              { "-val": "Protected Mailboxes" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "82" },
              { "-val": "VaultTracker Enterprise" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "143" },
              { "-val": "Virtual Server" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "6" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cellValue": [
              { "-val": "43621" },
              { "-val": "90" },
              { "-val": "WORM Media Support" },
              { "-val": "0" },
              { "-val": "1" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I am trying to load, An error is displayed in the console

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/snehareddy/Desktop/Moni/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.send @ jquery.min.js:4

How to solve this issue and how to display the JSON data in HTML table format.

Comment: Cross origin see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Comment: load it from http, not a file. use an `<input type=file>` if it has to be locally loaded.

Comment: also, might want to look into a templater like mustache for these kind of tasks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve your web site from a web server and not directly off the file system.

Install a web-server like [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) and your example should work assuming that `data.json` is coming from the same place as your JavaScript file.

More information about [cross origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

A pretty common problem, see this: http://ahmed.amayem.com/solution-to-chrome-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-http-data-chrome-chrome-extension-https-chrome-extension-resource/

Simpler: you are not allowed to pull data from a separate domain, or e.g. if you are doing this locally `file:///C:/Users/snehareddy/Desktop/Moni/data.json` try installing XAMP or a webserver in order to achieve it.